# Pandas Dataframes - new dataframe with reorganized data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm new to Pandas and trying to create a new dataframe from an existing one.

My current dataframe has a format:

```
ID   Country    Status  
ABC  USA        Go
ABC  Columbia   Stop
ABC  Japan      Pause
ABC  Egypt      Go 
DEF  Canada     Go
DEF  Peru       Stop
```

I'm trying to consolidate the data to make it more compact. My new format is:

```
ID   Go          Stop      Pause
ABC  USA, Egypt  Columbia  Japan
DEF  Canada      Peru
```

Basically, the possible Status values become the columns and, for each ID, these columns are populated with a list of countries having that status. I'm 
new to pandas and struggling with the best way to approach this - any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. What is the purpose?

Comment: @Denziloe, In my opinion, the output is no worse than the input. At least we don't have lists in those series.

Comment: @Denzlioe it's largely for presentation purposes - the actual data I'm working with has many more columns than those shown here for simplicity. My users prefer to have one row per ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
res = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Status', values='Country', aggfunc=', '.join)

print(res)

Status          Go  Pause      Stop
ID                                 
ABC     USA, Egypt  Japan  Columbia
DEF         Canada   None      Peru
```

Comment: Thanks, @jpp. This worked like a charm. Thanks for helping a beginner out.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely must do this then this is how you do it.

```
In [48]: df.groupby(['ID', 'Status'])['Country'].apply(','.join).unstack()
Out[48]:
Status         Go  Pause      Stop
ID
ABC     USA,Egypt  Japan  Columbia
DEF        Canada    NaN      Peru
```